# How to use a method on a prop of and object, then return object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying to reproduce the appendSearchParam function using Ramda, i.e.  applying a method of a prop of an object and then returning said object.

My best shot was the provided aSP function, but this function does not return the url object, and I seriously doubt my "nthArg" are a very good practice. I've then tried to use R.tap with aSP, but no result.

```
import {
    URL
} from 'url'
import R from 'ramda'

const u = new URL('http://www.google.com')

const appendSearchParam = (url, key, value) => {
    url.searchParams.append(key, value)
    return url
}

const aSP = R.converge(
    R.invoker(2, 'append'),
    [
        R.nthArg(1),
        R.nthArg(2),
        R.prop('searchParams')
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that using `nthArg` is bad practice. However I'm not sure the indexes are correct. It should be `nthArg(0)` and `nthArg(1)` instead I think.

You probably want to use `useWith` instead anyway, in this case you don't need to use `nthArg` but `identity` to return `key` and `value` respectively.

```
const asp = useWith(
  invoker(2, 'append'), [
    identity,               // return key
    identity,               // return value
    prop('searchParams')]); // get 'searchParams' from url
```

The problem isn't the function but the API that you're interacting with. As you can see [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) will return `undefined` but still append your query:

```js
const url = new URL('http://foo.bar');

console.log(url.searchParams.append('x', 42));
console.log(url);
```

I'm not sure a point-free function would make sense here as you'd need a reference to `url` in order to return it.

I'd probably do something like this instead:

```
const asp = curry((key, value, url) =>
  url.searchParams.append(key, value) || url);
```

Comment: I think I just fell in the "just discovered Ramda, want to use it on every line" trap. Thank you very much !

Comment: To avoid mutating the url, I modified a bit your answer to :
```const appendSearchParam = curry(
  (key, value, url) =>
  ((u) => u.searchParams.append(key, value) || u)(clone(url))
)```